# How Integrated Circuit works?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I've been searching for a while about *How Integrated Circuit works?* but I can't really get the answer, all that is said is that they are made out of lots of transistor (logic gates) and nothing else...

The only thing transistor (logic gates) does is compare whether there is an electric current or none (on/off, 1/0).

How everything else happen? do complex things, store information in the Computer, play games, display text on the screen, etc...

Comment: *but I can't really get the answer* As if there can be an answer in just a few lines. It took me **years** to understand everything that falls under your question here and you think that can be summarized is a few lines ? It can't. So my answer is: **It works by magic**. If you want the real answer: start by reading a book about electronics.

Comment: You've asked us to provide a short answer on a subject on which there are entire books.  The reason you can't find a simple, single answer is that it is not simple and can't be summed up in single answer.

Comment: Try [Code](http://www.charlespetzold.com/code/) by Petzold for a bottom up approach.

Comment: *"How Integrated Circuit works?"* Usually pretty well, just like the datasheet says it does.

Comment: Integrated circuits are just a bunch of semiconductor components compressed into a black package... essentially.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that you have to layer the question, in order to ask sensible questions, and understand the answers. This simplifies the context of each question and answer.

Consider a human example. Cells in the body work by protein synthesis, and movement and conversion of energy molecules like ATP. So how do we understand why the people in the UK voted for Brexit?

It's totally impossible to go from low level cell operations to political sensibilities in a single leap. You have to understand politics in the context of groups of people who try to keep their own identity, while cooperating with other groups. This is where social scientists work. You understand groups in the context of organisms that preserve their own existence, and further their own fitness, by cooperating with other organisms. Social biology maybe? You understand organisms as collections of specialised cells that are controlled by this chemical and that process. Biologists and biochemists work here.

Note that there's a big big leap from the low level biology of the system to ideas of behaviour and politics.

Similarly, we understand 'play games and display text on screen' as operations on information. This information is stored and manipulated on a computer, and controlled by ideas expressed in a high level language. Programmers and systems analysts play here. The computer is built from RAM and ALU, which is itself built from flip-flops and address decoders, and adders and logic operations. System designers and chip engineers work here. These low level devices are built from transistors. This is what the process engineers in the chip design houses worry about. The transistors work by charge movements on patterned conductor and semiconductor materials. Physicists start cranking up their involvement here, and the theoretical ones carry on down further into quantum mechanics and all sorts of other stuff I neither understand nor need to know about.

Note that there's a big leap from the electrical engineering of transistors and CPUs to ideas of behaviour and information, and control by programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general. A complete answer giving any real detail would be impossible to post on this site so here's a quick summary:

By using a lot of 0's and 1's

Here's a slightly longer summary:

If you use 4 transistors you can make a 2 input NAND or NOR gate. The [Wikipedia page on NAND gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) shows you how to do this.

Using NAND or NOR gates you can make any basic logic gate. That allows you to perform any arbitrary logic function you want between two or more inputs.
Using logic gates you can make things like [binary adders](http://www.edwardbosworth.com/CPSC2105/Lectures/Slides_05/Chapter_03/BinaryAdders.htm) or latches like a [d-type flip flop](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/dflipflop.html) which is in effect a single bit memory.

If you can store information and perform basic maths then given enough time you can do just about anything. For example [here](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/General/4004_schematic.pdf) is the schematic for the intel 4004, one of the very early processors.

After that everything is about improving performance by allowing more complex operations to be completed in less steps and less time and by adding more memory.